# CSS Change Columns from 1 to 2

Tags: css, flexbox, multiple-columns, column-count

In mobile view, footer navigation menu displays in 1 column at https://wordl.io

Need help changing 1 column to 2 columns in footer navigation menu.

Tried css below but does not work.

.gh-foot-menu .nav {column-count:2;}

Comment: can i see the code ?

Comment: you can take this code in your ul list : style="display: ruby;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've check this and you can try my code

```
ul.nav {
columns: 2;
-webkit-columns: 2;
-moz-columns: 2;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. Any suggestions on column-gap? I tried adding: '''column-gap:2px;'''

Comment: For big display margin: 0 12px; amd for mobile add line-height: 30px;

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
    ul.nav {
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
    }
```

Where 50% is the width of the column